# Change sudo defaults only for sudo -i

Tags: sudo

At my site the typical sudoers setup has `Defaults mail_always` globally set so we can keep track of what the users are generally using sudo for (which should be very infrequent) and sort out fixing the permissions for common actions. This is disabled per role account that needs to execute things as root.

We've shifted to a policy of discourage direct logins as role accounts for the purposes of auditing and preventing the role users from becoming "party accounts".  Thus, we have a lot of logins as a regular user than then immediately invoke `sudo -u <role account> -i`.  I would really like to set `!mail_always` just for the `-i` action (which AFAIK, there is no way to specific set rules for -i in sudo) or user X running a command as just user foo.  Is this possible?  I feel the syntax should be something like this:

```
Defaults[:!>]realuser ALL = (roleuser) NOPASSWD: ALL !mail_always
```

UPDATE:

I've found a livable, if not ideal solution:

```
Defaults>ROLE_ACCOUNTS !mail_always
%wheel ALL = (ROLE_ACCOUNTS) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This isn't ideal as any user, not just the members of the wheel group, will not generate email notifications when running commands or invoking login shells as one of the role accounts.